# How to retrieve appended authorization header's access token from custom RestTemplate implementation?

Tags: spring, rest, resttemplate

I have a custom RestTemplate class that extends the RestTemplate class. Purpose of it is to append an access token to it for users to use in making API requests.

The class looks like this:

```
public class ModifiedRestTemplate extends RestTemplate {
    private String token;

    private void setInterceptorWithAuthorizationHeaders() {
        super.getInterceptors().clear();
        super.getInterceptors().add((request, body, execution) -> {
            request.getHeaders().add("Authorization", "Bearer "+ this.token);
            return execution.execute(request, body);
        });
    }
```

I want to unit test this class and check that the header within the custom RestTemplate indeed contains the mocked access token (`this.token` in case you're still confused on my goal). Reason being there is another method within this class that triggers the updating of said access token in the custom RestTemplate. So I would like to test that the updating process was successful. I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

RestTemplate API has a `headForHeaders` method but this method returns an empty header (expected, since my mockServer setup includes an empty `success()` block anyway).

Code sample below:

```
mockServer.expect(ExpectedCount.once(), requestTo("http://localhost:8080/test/mock")).andExpect(method(HttpMethod.HEAD)).andRespond(withSuccess());

HttpHeaders httpHeaders = modifiedRestTemplate.headForHeaders("http://localhost:8080/test/mock");
```

Is there a way to reach into the custom RestTemplate object/instance and extract the header with its access token?